# Google sheets count consecutive occurrences

Tags: google-sheets

I have a complex year-long schedule for 25 people in google sheets and I need to quantify how often each individual has to work multiple nights in a row over the course of the entire year. I need to bin these into 2 nights in a row, 3 in a row, etc. Here is a simplified view of 1 week, in which I need to count consecutive occurrences of "Back Up IV Call". I have found some similar tasks using query function and vlookup but am having trouble adapting this to my data. Is anyone able to give me a hand with this?

[schedule week 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gao9.png)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=IFNA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 FILTER(BYROW(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE (TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B3:3="",, REGEXMATCH(B3:3, "Back Up IV Call" ))),"FALSE,","0"),"0",)),","), LAMBDA(vv, COUNTA(vv))), 
        BYROW(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE (TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B3:3="",, REGEXMATCH(B3:3, "Back Up IV Call" ))),"FALSE,","0"),"0",)),","), LAMBDA(vv, COUNTA(vv)))>1)),"No streak")
```

[image]

### Get the result in a table

Rename your input sheet to `Sheet1` 
And In another sheet, paste this formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(Sheet1!B3:B="",, { Sheet1!B3:B,SPLIT(Sheet1!A3:A, ", ", 0)}))
```

[image]

### Explanation

**01 -** [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)`(B3:3, "Back Up IV Call" )`
To get array of `TRUE` / `FALSE`

**02 -** `IF(B3:3="",,` 
IF `B3:3` cells is empty `""` then do nothing `,,` IF not excute the [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) formula.

**03 -** [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)`(",",1,IF(B3:3="",,` [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)`(B3:3, "Back Up IV Call" )))`
To [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) the `TRUE` / `FALSE` array with `","`.

**04 -** [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)`(`[`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)`(...)`
To Replace `"FALSE,"` with a `0`.

**05 -** [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)`(`[`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)`(`[`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)`(...)`
To Split the jointed arrar "cell" with `0` set as a delimiter.

**06 -** [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)`(...)`
To Flatten the streaks in one column for example `TRUE` | `TRUE,TRUE` in one column

`TRUE`
+-----------+
`TRUE,TRUE`

**07 -** [`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en)`(`[`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)`(`[`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)`(...),` [`LAMBDA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)`(vv,` [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en)`(vv))`
To [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) [`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) the splited cells of the Array from this:

`TRUE`
+-----------+
`TRUE`,`TRUE`

**To this**

`TRUE`
+-----------+
`TRUE` | `TRUE`

**08 -** [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)`(`[`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en)`(...),` [`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en)`(...)>1)`
To Flatten the streaks in one column for example `TRUE` | `TRUE,TRUE` in one column 
To [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) the counted list and accept only values `>` 1 Greater than 1.

**09 -** [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)`(", ", 1,`  [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)`(...)`
To join the array in one cell with `", "` as a delimiter.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hi @JCO Welcome to stackoverflow, please check if this answer is what you want.

Comment: @JCO Checkout the edit You can get the result in a table to make it easier to process it further.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Humbling to see how much I have to learn. I will try and go back to understand your solution as there are others I need to solve for this schedule and want to think this through myself. Thank you so much.