# Google Sheets Count Specific Sequences

Tags: google-sheets, count, array-formulas

I have a complex employee schedule spanning one year with 25 individuals in a Google Sheets format. Each individual may have more than one duty on a given day and these are delimited by commas currently. Here is a shortened and simplified sample as I cannot attach the original sheet to respect anonymity of coworkers:

|  | 1/1/2022 | 1/2/2022 | 1/3/2022 | 1/4/2022 | 1/5/2022 | 1/6/2022 | 1/7/2022 | 1/8/2022 | 1/9/2022 | 1/10/2022 | 1/11/2022 | 1/12/2022 | 1/13/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 |  |  | Office, , | Lab, , | Office, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, Night Call , | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Office, , |
| Person 2 | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Office, , | Office, , | , , | , , | Office, , | Office, , | Office, , | Office, , |
| Person 3 | Back Up Call | Night Call, Rounder, | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Office,, | Office, , | Lab, , | Lab, , | , , | , , | Office, , | Lab, , | Office, , | Rounder, , |
| Person 4 | , | , | Vacation, | Vacation, | Office, | Rounder, | Rounder, | Rounder, | Night Call, Rounder | Rounder, | Rounder, | Rounder, | Office, |
| Person 5 | , | , | Vacation, | Back Up Call, | Night Call, , | Back Up Call, | Vacation, | , | , | Vacation, | Vacation, | Vacation, | Vacation, |

To ensure fairness, I need to quantify how often certain events occur. I was helped greatly by member [Osm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19529694/osm) with a solution to [Count the same event occurring multiple days in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748568/19529694). I have worked through that solution and understand it now, but have hit another snag. I need to count the frequency of the following sequences:

-Back Up Call | Back Up Call | Night Call

-Back Up Call | Night Call   | Back Up Call

-Night Call   | Back Up Call | Back Up Call

I would like the output to look something like this:

|  | Backup/Backup/Call | Backup/Call/Backup | Call/Backup/Backup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Person 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Person 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Person 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| Person 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

So far I have tried variations of IF function but I am new to array formulas and the difference in syntax that is allowed is tripping me up. I have also begun working through using REGEXREPLACE and representing each of these various text strings as a different number and getting sums, but this does not allow me to determine the order the shifts occurred in.

Does anyone have a solution which might work for this? Thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Show expected(desired) output as a table for the shown input table.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant ansswer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited my post above with a sample of what I am trying to achieve with the output and what I have attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get the count

**Use this formula** to get the count

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($E$3:$E$509="",, 
{BYROW($F3:$509, 
       LAMBDA(v, COUNTIF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
       IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(LAMBDA(x,y, IF(COLUMN(x)<=MAX(IF(y="",,COLUMN(x))),IF(y="","Empty", y),""))(v,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(v, ", ,|(,)[^,]*$", "")))), " Where Col1 <> '' ")), 
              REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(A$2), " \| ", "|")),"NaError"), "[[:punct:]]", ""))), 
                               REGEXREPLACE(A$2, " \| ", ","), "♥"), ","), "=♥"))),
  BYROW($F3:$509, 
       LAMBDA(v, COUNTIF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
       IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(LAMBDA(x,y, IF(COLUMN(x)<=MAX(IF(y="",,COLUMN(x))),IF(y="","Empty", y),""))(v,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(v, ", ,|(,)[^,]*$", "")))), " Where Col1 <> '' ")), 
              REGEXREPLACE(TRIM($B$2), " \| ", "|")),"NaError"), "[[:punct:]]", ""))), 
                               REGEXREPLACE(B$2, " \| ", ","), "♥"), ","), "=♥"))),
  BYROW($F3:$509, 
       LAMBDA(v, COUNTIF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
       IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(LAMBDA(x,y, IF(COLUMN(x)<=MAX(IF(y="",,COLUMN(x))),IF(y="","Empty", y),""))(v,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(v, ", ,|(,)[^,]*$", "")))), " Where Col1 <> '' ")), 
              REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(C$2), " \| ", "|")),"NaError"), "[[:punct:]]", ""))), 
                               REGEXREPLACE(C$2, " \| ", ","), "♥"), ","), "=♥")))}))
```

[image]

### Display table

Assuming the first tab is named `Sheet1`, paste this formula in another sheet

```
=ArrayFormula({ "Persons", REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!A2:C2, " \| ", CHAR(10)); Sheet1!E3:E, Sheet1!A3:C})
```

[image]

### Named function

See [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en) how you can create a named function to make the workflow easier. or [***make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3-19IQYLP3WHO7M7sped2oJBOnl5H0pHRMnJmZjrTs/copy) of this sheet example.

and this [demo](https://i.imgur.com/VURKa3I.gif) on how to use it.

[image]

**Notes**

Keep an eye on the range `$F3:$500` and `$E$3:$E$500` If you have less or more than 500, adjust accordingly. I set it to 500 to avoid missing references.

**Resources**

```
|               **Streaks of**               |                                            |                                            |   |          |              |                      |                        |               |               |               |                       |                        |                        |            |            |            |            |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|:------------------------------------------:|:------------------------------------------:|:------------------------------------------:|:-:|----------|--------------|----------------------|------------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|------------------------|------------------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|--------------|------------|--------------|---|--------------|------------|--------------|
| Back Up Call \| Back Up Call \| Night Call | Back Up Call \| Night Call \| Back Up Call | Night Call \| Back Up Call \| Back Up Call |   | 1/1/2022 |   1/2/2022   |       1/3/2022       |        1/4/2022        |    1/5/2022   |    1/6/2022   |    1/7/2022   |        1/8/2022       |        1/9/2022        |        1/10/2022       |  1/11/2022 |  1/12/2022 |  1/13/2022 |            |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|             **0[Formula Here]**            |                      0                     |                      1                     |   | Person 1 |              |                      | Office, ,              | Lab, ,        | Office, ,     | Rounder, ,    | Rounder, Night Call , | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Rounder, , | Office, ,  |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|                      0                     |                      0                     |                      0                     |   | Person 2 | Rounder, ,   | Rounder, ,           | Rounder, ,             | Rounder, ,    | Rounder, ,    | Office, ,     | Office, ,             | , ,                    | , ,                    | Office, ,  | Office, ,  | Office, ,  | Office, ,  |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|                      0                     |                      1                     |                      0                     |   | Person 3 | Back Up Call | Night Call, Rounder, | Back Up Call, Rounder, | Office,,      | Office, ,     | Lab, ,        | Lab, ,                | , ,                    | , ,                    | Office, ,  | Lab, ,     | Office, ,  | Rounder, , |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|                      0                     |                      0                     |                      0                     |   | Person 4 | ,            | ,                    | Vacation,              | Vacation,     | Office,       | Rounder,      | Rounder,              | Rounder,               | Night Call, Rounder    | Rounder,   | Rounder,   | Rounder,   | Office,    |              |            |              |   |              |            |              |
|                      0                     |                      3                     |                      0                     |   | Person 5 | ,            | ,                    | Vacation,              | Back Up Call, | Night Call, , | Back Up Call, | Vacation,             | ,                      | ,                      | Vacation,  | Vacation,  | Vacation,  | Vacation,  | Back Up Call | Night Call | Back Up Call |   | Back Up Call | Night Call | Back Up Call |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I noticed that it was working for row 7 but it missed the occurrence in L3:N3. I believe this is because there is more text in these cells that becomes interposed and does not match exactly with the C2 text string. Is there a way to replace "some other text, Night Call" with "Night Call" and "Backup Call, some other text" with "Backup Call", etc?

Comment: @JCO If it worked, let me know and come back for more.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the incredible generosity with your time and knowledge. I don't know if I could have ever solved this problem without your assistance. You are making a positive difference in the lives of a number of people by helping me with this project. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @JCO I arranged the columns correctly make sure to use the latest update, and checkout the named function to make this workflow fast in the future just make a copy of the example and enjoy, if you need anything else let me know.